# Nginx only has drwx------ for directories

Tags: git, nginx, permissions, directory, docker-compose

currently Im using a docker-compose-yml to create my webserver. It looks like this:

```
nginx:
  restart: always
  image: prooph/nginx:www
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  links:
    - php:php
  volumes_from:
    - dataphp

php:
  restart: always
  image: prooph/php:7.0-fpm
  links:
    - database
  volumes_from:
    - dataphp

dataphp:
  image: debian:jessie
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www

database:
  restart: always
  image: mariadb:10.1.20
  ports:
        - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
    - MYSQL_USER=****
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=****
```

The whole app works as expected (including the database init) but my current problem is that the nginx container only has drwx------ rights for my directories and therefore I get a "403 Forbidden" error when trying to connect.
I know that i can fix this by logging in to the webserver and running "chmod +rx" on those directories.

ls -l on the server shows the following:

```
total 60
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  1817 Jan 11 15:27 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  2566 Jan 11 15:27 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   140 Jan 11 15:27 composer.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 26565 Jan 12 08:17 composer.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   656 Jan 12 08:30 docker-compose.yml
drwx------ 2 1000 1000  4096 Jan 12 08:15 public
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000  1116 Jan 11 15:27 showTables.sh
drwxrwxr-x 9 1000 1000  4096 Jan 12 08:17 vendor
drwx------ 2 1000 1000  4096 Jan 12 08:15 views
```

My original project (that I pushed to git aswell) has all the needed rights. When getting the project from git it's missing the rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem + solution:

I downloaded the repo instead of cloning it and for some reason .zip files ignore the predefined the permissions / don't save them.

So when downloading I had `drwx------`

When cloning I had `drwxrw-rw-` which is what I pushed the code with and need aswell.